# Not able to find out gradle dependency for xmlparserv2.jar

Tags: xml, maven

not able to find out dependency for "xmlparserv2.jar" in Gradle.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Your build file might be quite helpful, for example.

Comment: compile files('./src/main/resources/xmlparserv2.jar')   xmlparserv2.jar is in my local path .Since i do not found the dependency  for xmlparserv2.jar in Gradle file